# Filtering addresses matching condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2, jmespath, json-query

I want to provide list of allowed VLAN's as a variable to my server.

Ansible playbook should be able to filter server's IP addreses based on this VLAN's.

- I have a list of all IP addresses available on server (`ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` from ansible facts)
- I have a global variable `my_subnets`:

  ```
  my_subnets:
    - vlan: 2
      subnet: "192.168.2.0/24"
      gateway: "192.168.2.10"
    - vlan: 3
      subnet: "192.168.3.0/24"
      dns: "192.168.3.12"
    - vlan: 4
      subnet: "192.168.4.0/24"
    - vlan: 5
      subnet: "192.168.5.0/24"
  ```
- And I have per-service variable `allowed_vlans`:

  ```
  allowed_vlans:
    - 2
    - 5
  ```

I am looking for a way how to template out just `"192.168.2.0/24"` and `"192.168.5.0/24"`

---

I was thinking about:

### 1. Jinja way

Something like *extract* from `my_subnets` items *matching* `allowed_vlans` and *map* them with `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` through *ipaddr()* filter.

### 2. JSON query way

I've tried:

```
{{ my_subnets | json_query('[?vlan in allowed_vlans].subnet') }}
```

but it seems the json_query is not using python syntax for evaluating if something is in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`contains()`](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains) function is how JMESPath checks for membership, but as best I can tell it has no ability to refer *upward* in the object tree, nor assign expressions to internal variables as does the `jq` language. But, one can cheat and serialize the expression to JSON and then use JMESPath's [literal expression](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions) syntax:

```
tasks:
- debug:
    verbosity: 0
    msg: |
      {{ my_subnets | json_query(jq) }}
  vars:
    # this "vars" trick was recommended by the json_query docs, but isn't required
    jq: |
      [? contains(`{{ allowed_subnets | to_json }}`, vlan) ].subnet
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working flawlessly. Obvious requirements are `jmespath` and `jq` installed on control machine.

Comment: "and jq installed on control machine" I am not aware of anything within ansible that requires, or even uses, jq. And, AFAIK, jmespath is shipped with ansible -- or at least I don't recall taking steps to install it