# Filter list by multiple tests/conditions

Tags: ansible, jinja2

What is a jinja way to filter list of IP addresses using list of subnets to obtain list of IP addresses present in those subnets?

In general terms, I would like to filter a sequence of objects by applying multiple tests to each object, and only selecting the objects with at least one test succeeding.

Here are more details:

I have a list of IP addresses of a server from ansible facts:

```
"ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
    "192.168.1.108",
    "192.168.10.108",
    "192.168.20.108",
    "192.168.30.108"
]
```

And I have a list of IP subnets in which the service should be enabled (gained through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160078/filtering-addresses-matching-condition)):

```
"allowed_subnets": [
    "192.168.1.0/24",
    "192.168.5.0/24",
    "192.168.10.0/24",
    "192.168.30.0/24"
]
```

There is also a [ipaddr filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html) in Ansible, which [can be used](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#filtering-lists) to filter a list of IP addresses for those included in specified subnet like this:

```
# {{ test_list | ipaddr('192.0.0.0/8') }}
['192.24.2.1', '192.168.32.0/24']
```

---

I have tried this:

```
subnet_list:
  - "192.168.1.1"
  - "192.168.2.1"
  - "192.168.3.1"
  - "192.168.4.1"
  - "192.168.5.1"
```

and

```
{{ subnet_list | ipaddr("192.168.1.0/23", "192.168.5.0/24") }}
```

but the result is empty list, therefore I assume `ipaddr` filter is using *logical AND*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may start you down the trail of what you are looking for.

I created a role to test what you are asking for.  I have the following in vars/main.yml:

```
---
my_ipv4_addresses: [
  '192.168.1.108',
  '192.168.10.108',
  '192.168.20.108',
  '192.168.30.108'
]
my_allowed_subnets: [
  '192.168.1.0/24',
  '192.168.5.0/24',
  '192.168.10.0/24',
  '192.168.30.0/24'
]
...
```

I have the following task:

```
---
- name: "Get list of IPv4 only addresses within a given subnet"
  debug:  msg="For {{ item }}= {{ my_ipv4_addresses | ipv4(item) }}"
  with_items: "{{ my_allowed_subnets }}"
...
```

It generates the following output:

```
TASK [ipaddr : Get list of IPv4 only addresses within a given subnet] **********
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "For 192.168.1.0/24= [u'192.168.1.108']"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "For 192.168.5.0/24= []"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "For 192.168.10.0/24= [u'192.168.10.108']"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "For 192.168.30.0/24= [u'192.168.30.108']"
}
```

So, may be able to get by using something like this loop, or generating a list from this loop.

Hope this helps.